# create partition using ansible

Tags: ubuntu, partition, ansible

I need to run those commands, but I do not want to use 'shell', is there way to create home partition using ansible tools?

```
lvcreate -L5G -n home vg0
mkdir /home
mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/vg0-home
mount /dev/mapper/vg0-home /home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `community.general.lvol` module to [manage logical volumes.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lvg_module.html)

```yml
- name: Create a logical volume home with 5g
  community.general.lvol:
    vg: vg0
    lv: home
    size: 5g
```

Use `ansible.builtin.file` to [create the directory.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)

```yml
- name: Create /home directory
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /home
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

The `community.general.filesystem` module allows you [to create filesystems.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filesystem_module.html)

```yml
- name: Create xfs filesystem on vg0-home
  community.general.filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: /dev/mapper/vg0-home
```

Finally, `ansible.posix.mount` lets you [mount what you created.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html)

```yml
- name: Mount home volume
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: /home
    src: /dev/mapper/vg0-home
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
```

This can be generalized by introducing variables for the FS type, mount point, volume size, volume name and volume group name.

Answer (score -1):

At Ansible 2.9

lvol  will do lvcreate
file  will do mkdir
filesystem for mkfs
mount will handle mount